WordClouds in matplotlib-set-diagrams by Word Frequency
I would like to create Venn Diagram WordClouds for two sets of words. matplotlib-set-diagrams https://github.com/paulbrodersen/matplotlib_set_diagrams (matplotlib-venn is now deprecated) works great but the font sizes used for each word do not correspond to the word frequencies in each set.
matplotlib-set-diagrams calls word-cloud, which has a nice example of what I would like for a single set of words https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/auto_examples/frequency.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-frequency-py but I would like to combine the two approaches. Obviously a brute force way of doing it would be to create three separate masks for wordlist1 only, wordlist2 only and wordlist1+2 but that is clearly an inelegant way of doing it. Any suggestions?
Thanks, Simon

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

(matplotlib-venn is not deprecated, although it does not do wordclouds so obviously not applicable here)
